# Why do some logarithmic equations have two solutions?

Tags: logarithms

I was trying to find solutions for a high school math problem, but there was one thing I didn't quite understand.

There is a logarithmic identity that says that

$ln\:x^2=2\cdot ln \:x$

However, when solving an equation, the two different forms give different solutions
When graphing in Geogebra, or trying to solve with wolframalpha, $ 2 \cdot ln\:x=1$   has only a positive answer to the equation ($\sqrt e$)

But when using $ln\:x^2=1$, I also get the solutions for negative x   ($\:\sqrt e, -\sqrt e)$.

If these forms are exactly the same, why do they give different solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct identity is

$$\log x^2=2\log |x|.$$

Comment: Thanks! It's weird that it's not mentioned anywhere in the book

Comment: @ZackKing: this is because $x^2=|x|^2$, nothing to do with logarithms.

Answer (score 2):

$\ln(x^2) = 2\ln(x)$ only holds for $x > 0$.

Comment: It does really seem like that, but shouldn't the texbook at least mention that? Thank you for the answer though :))

Comment: I agree, but I guess this is implied as $\ln(x)$ was probably only defined for $x > 0$ anyway.